# Relation between diagonal entries of $A^{-1}$ and inverse values of $a_{ii}$ for positive definite $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I'd like to expand upon [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945577/diagonal-entries-of-inverse-larger-than-1-over-those-for-the-original-matrix). Namely, it says that if $A$, $A=A^T$, is a positive definite matrix, then it holds that \begin{equation}\tag{*}(A^{-1})_{ii}\ge \frac1{A_{ii}}.\end{equation}
Can we prove the converse, i.e.,

*if (*) holds for all $1\le i\le n$, then $A$ is positive definite?*

OK, as suggested by @Klaus and @Jan I accept this answer and continue [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778523/condition-of-positive-definiteness-based-upon-diagonal-elements-of-the-original).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's even wrong for numbers, e.g. $A = -1$.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I'll try to specify my question to exclude the case you've pointed at.

Comment: @Dmitry Sure. However, you should ask a new question (possibly with a link here) instead of editing this one. Otherwise people might get confused if the answer does not fit the question.

Comment: I've chosen to update the question, while explicitly mentioning your answer. I'm afraid that posting two questions with the same subject would confuse people as well...

Comment: @Dmitry I don't think that this is a good idea. You should rollback your question, accept the answer given by Klaus, and then ask a new question with a reference (link) to this question.