# Condition of positive definiteness based upon diagonal elements of the original and inverse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, inverse, positive-definite

This is a sequel to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778415/relation-between-diagonal-entries-of-a-1-and-inverse-values-of-a-ii-for) in which I sought to expand on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945577/diagonal-entries-of-inverse-larger-than-1-over-those-for-the-original-matrix). Let me put it straight. Given a non-singular symmetric real matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A_{ii}>0$.

Can we conclude that $A$ is positive definite if
$$(A^{-1})_{ii}\ge \frac1{A_{ii}}$$
holds for all $1\le i\le n$?

Comment: Don't you also have to assume $A$ to be invertible?

Comment: Well, yes. Otherwise the question doesn't make much sense. I added this condition explicitly in the question.

Comment: Possibly useful: let $D$ denote the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $A_{11},\dots,A_{nn}$. Let $B = D^{-1}AD^{-1}$. We note that $A$ is positive definite iff $B$ is positive definite, and  $B^{-1} = DA^{-1}D$ satisfies $(B^{-1})_{ii} \geq 1$.

In other words, it suffices to consider the case where $A_{ii} = 1$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Random counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{ 2& 3&-3\\ 3& 2&-3\\-3&-3& 4},
\ A^{-1}=\frac12\pmatrix{1&3&3\\ 3&1&3\\ 3&3&5}.
$$
$A$ is nonsingular as its determinant is $-2$, but $A$ isn't positive definite as it has an eigenvector $(1,-1,0)^T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$.