# Diagonal entries of inverse larger than 1 over those for the original matrix - non symmetric case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know (see for instance here [Diagonal entries of inverse larger than 1 over those for the original matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945577/diagonal-entries-of-inverse-larger-than-1-over-those-for-the-original-matrix/4668133?noredirect=1#comment9865362_4668133))
that if $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, then

$(A^{−1})_{jj} A_{jj} \geq 1$ .

Assume $A$ is positive definite, but not symmetric (i.e. $x^T A x > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$).

Do we still have that $(A^{−1})_{jj} A_{jj} \geq 1$ ?

Comment: The situation you’re describing is impossible. If $A$ has a negative eigenvalue $\lambda$, then say $x$ is a unit eigenvector; then $x^T Ax = x^T (\lambda x) = \lambda(x^T x) = \lambda < 0$, so $A$ cannot be positive definite. Positive definite matrices have only strictly positive eigenvalues. 

Now, it might be the case that $A$ is not diagonalizable if $A$ is positive definite but not symmetric. I’m not certain, but you might consider using the result that every complex matrix is expressible as $A = D + N$, with $D$ diagonalizable and $N$ nilpotent.

Comment: @ D Ford, I edited the question, I made a stupid confusion. Of course $A$'s real eigenvalues are strictly positive, and the complex ones have strictly positive real part. Sorry. My question makes sense now I think.